# авто запуск программы при подключении флешки

Tags: windows, bat, usb, exe, flash-память

Как сделать чтобы при подключении usb накопителя открывался exe файл находяйщейся на этом носителе ?

Пробовал делать через `[autorun]`:

```
[autorun]
OPEN=CpuZ.exe
```

но это не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты сейчас изобрёл автозагрузку, через которую в середине нулевых любили запускаться не только красивые заставки игр, но и вирусы. Любой уважающий себя админ отрубает эту штуку на своих компах в первую очередь. Даже если ты у себя включишь и оно поедет - опыт в 90% случаев будет не переносим. Оставь эту идею.

Comment: ок, спасибо за инфу )